# Should this be called some special case of object slicing?

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, terminology, pointer-arithmetic

Let's say I have a class `Derived` which derives from class `Base` whereas `sizeof(Derived) > sizeof(Base)`. Now, if one allocates an array of `Derived` like this:

```
Base * myArray = new Derived[42];
```

and then attempts to access the `n`-th object using

```
doSomethingWithBase(myArray[n]);
```

Then this is might likely (but not always) cause undefined behaviour due to accessing `Base` from an invalid location.

**What is the correct term for such an programming error?** Should it be considered a case of [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)?

Comment: "Using C-style arrays and pointers and `new`". That's the name of this programmer's error.

Comment: @n.m. this is not C-style array but classic dynamic array, I think OP raised very good question - completely legit code by syntax leads to disaster

Comment: Allocating arrays of anything that's not plain old C structures - that's your problem right there.

Comment: @Slava Not limited as such, but you really want to wrap them in a class that manages them properly, such as std::vector :)

Comment: @Slava That's classic dynamic **C-style** array. A C-style array is a sequence of objects exposed via a raw pointer to its first element. It doesn't matter how it is allocated.

Comment: @Slava *completely legit code by syntax leads to disaster* This is just your run-off-the-mill undefined behavior, nothing special.

Comment: @Slava Use `std::vector` (I don't believe I still have to say that several times a day).

Comment: @n.m. how vector allocates data inside? It is using new[] is it not? But according to you that's programmer's error

Comment: @Slava That's irrelevant to OP's question; please avoid asking here.

Comment: @Slava `how vector allocates data inside` is not anyone's buiness. It is guaranteed by the standard to work, that's all users need to know. `new`, if used, is called by the standard library. The standard library is allowed to use stuff whuch is not accessible or not advised for the users of the library.

Comment: Huh, I never thought of this. A legal implicit pointer conversion resulting in total nonsense code, really easily. Good going, C++!

Comment: @Slava: _"how vector allocates data inside? It is using new[] is it not?"_ Yes but `new char[]` most likely, then placement new into that buffer. Not related to this question in any way.

Comment: As a German I suggest ___Arrayelementsizemismatch___ as the correct term. Mhmm. Gotta shove a "base" in there somewhere...

Comment: In the special case where 42 is instead 1, it would be object slicing. But, really it's that since it is possible that sizeof(Base) != sizeof(Derived), array indexing gets the wrong memory location. If the sizeof(Base) == sizeof(Derived), then again it is object slicing. Object slicing is a special case of this!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### This is not object slicing.

As noted, indexing `myArray` does not cause object slicing, but results in undefined behavior caused by indexing into an array of `Derived` as if it were an array of `Base`.

### A kind of "array decay bug".

The bug introduced at the assignment of `new Derived[42]` to `myArray` may be a variation of an **array decay bug**.

In a true instance of this type of bug, there is an actual array:

```
Derived x[42];
Base *myArray = x;
```

The problem is introduced because an array of `Derived` decays into a pointer to `Derived` with value equal to the address of its first element. The decay allows the pointer assignment to work properly. This decay behavior is inherited from C, which was a language design feature to allow arrays to be "passed by reference".

This leads us to the even worse incarnation of this bug. This feature gives C and C++ semantics for arrays syntax that turn array function arguments into aliases for pointer arguments.

```
void foo (Base base_array[42]) {
    //...
}

Derived d[42];
foo(d);          // Boom.
```

However, `new[]` is actually an overloaded operator that returns a pointer to the beginning of the allocated array object. So it is not a true instance of array decay (even though the array allocator is used). However, the bug symptoms are the same, and the intention of `new[]` is to get an array of `Derived`.

### Detecting and avoiding the bug.

#### Use a smart pointer.

This kind of problem can be avoided by using a smart pointer object instead of managing a raw pointer. For example, the analogous coding error with `unique_ptr` would look like:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base[]> myArray = new Derived[42];
```

This would yield a compile time error, because `unique_ptr`s constructor is `explicit`

#### Use a container, and maybe `std::reference`.

Alternatively, you could avoid using `new[]`, and use `std::vector<Derived>`. Then, you would have forced yourself to design a different solution for sending this array to framework code that is only `Base` aware. Possibly, a template function.

```
void my_framework_code (Base &object) {
    //...
}

template <typename DERIVED>
void my_interface(std::vector<DERIVED> &v) {
    for (...) {
        my_framework_code(v[i]);
    }
}
```

Or, by using `std::reference_wrapper<Base>`.

```
std::vector<Derived> v(42);
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Base>> myArray(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Comment: If the sizes are the same, it will most likely work. Does the standard have anything to say about that?

Comment: @sp2danny: Once the array-to-pointer conversion is performed, the `Base` pointer must be treated as a pointer to a nonarray object. Only a `Derived` pointer can be treated as a pointer to an array object. Thus, pointer arithmetic on the `Base` pointer is limited to what is defined for an array of length one.

Comment: @jxh So contrary to ruakh's comment on n.m.'s answer, `myArray + 0` is NOT undefined behaviour?

Comment: @sp2danny: Okay, found n.m.'s citation in C++2014.

Answer (score 26):

It is not slicing at all, rather it is undefined behavior because you are accessing a `Derived` object where none exists (unless you get lucky and the sizes line up, in which case it is still UB but might do something useful anyway).

It's a simple case of failed pointer arithmetic.

Comment: It's still undefined behaviour even if you "get lucky and the sizes line up". Pointers are pointers, not integers. Technically. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You're right, the way I worded that made it sound like it would be totally valid in that case but it's not.  I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 11):

This is not object slicing in any way.

Object slicing is perfectly well defined by the C++ standard. It may be a violation of object-oriented design principles or whatever, but it is not a violation of C++ rules.

This code violates [5.7 [expr.add] paragraph 7](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#expr.add-6):

> For addition or subtraction, if the expressions `P` or `Q` have type “pointer to *cv* `T`”, where `T` is different from the cv-unqualified array element type, the behavior is undefined. [Note: In particular, a pointer to a base class cannot be used for pointer arithmetic when the array contains objects of a derived class type. —end note].

Array subscript operator is defined to be equivalent to pointer arithmetic, [5.2.1 [expr.sub] paragraph 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#expr.sub-1):

> The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`

Comment: +1. Interestingly, this implies that even `myArray + 0` invokes undefined behavior. I wonder if any compilers currently use that fact for any weird optimizations?

Comment: @ruakh: They could use it to determine  that the dynamic type equals the static type and eliminate virtual function calls. Don't know, if any do though.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Object slicing is perfectly well defined by the C++ standard"*?

Comment: @jotik I mean object slicing does not violate any C++ rules. There's no undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MikeMB nice, that would be an excellent way to hint a compiler at the dynamic type of an object.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a case of slicing, although it is very similar. Slicing is well defined. This is simply undefined behaviour (always, not just likely) due to illegal pointer arithmetic.